# module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'Book'

Tags: python, excel, debugging, spyder, xlwings

I'm trying to use xlwings for the first time but I can't quite understand the documentation.
From the section "Quickstart"  I read

```
import xlwings as xw       

wb = xw.Book()  # this will create a new workbook
```

When I try this "at home", I have no problem importing xlwings but with the second script I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'Book'
```

When I try to see the attributes of xw I can see AboveBelow,ActionTime etc. but not Book.

Can you help please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of xlwings: `import xlwings` and `xlwings.__version__`

Comment: it was that (I found out that I had problem updating the package because of my work's proxy server.Thank you again, it was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I had the error also and changed from Workbook to Book.  It is a version issue.

wb = xw.Workbook()

Comment: You wrote you change from 'Workbook' to 'Book', yet you wrote 'Workbook' in you solution. So...?

Comment: Depending on the issue, you change Book to Workbook or Workbook to Book.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me:

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.book()
```

I opened the excel file and seen book written as Book(first capital letter), so I changed it in the code as below:

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... in my case it was the name of the file I used: "xlwings.py"
Do NOT use that name for the file or the containing folder or you'll get an error.