# Anaconda /Jupyter lab: AttributeError after changing directory

Tags: jupyter-lab, working-directory

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
```

The above code gives me the following error.

```
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'Book' 
(most likely due to a circular import)
```

At first, I thought it was due to changing the start folder by updating config file.

```
jupyter-notebook_config.py
...
## The directory to use for notebooks and kernels.
#  Default: ''
#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'E:\python\jupyterlab'
...
```

but when the code is not running in the default folder(c:\Users***), it gives me the same error.

please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'Book'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184203/module-xlwings-has-no-attribute-book)

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with Jupyter or JupyterLab. Other users reported such issues with xlwings without using Jupyter at all.